# Finite Field multiplication results in same set

Tags: finite-fields

In the book `Programming bitcoin` by Jimmy Song, the author provides an exercise for learning about finite fields:

```
for k = 1, 3, 7, 13, 18, what is this set in F(sub)19?
{k * 0, k * 1, k * 2, k * 3, .... k * 18}
Do you notice anything about these sets?
```

and then comments:

```
The answer to Exercise 5 is why we choose to use fields
with a prime number of elements. 
No matter what k you chose, as long as it's greater than 0, 
multiplying the entire set by k will result in the same set as you started with
```

If I multiply with e.g. 3 then I get {0, 3, 6, etc}, a different set

What does the author mean by "same set as you started with"?

Comment: I think there might be something missing from your setup of the problem.   Perhaps the  "multiplication" involved here is that of arithmetic modulo $19$?  Then you would have equal sets.

Comment: Keep going with your $0,3,6..$ example making sure to reduce mod 19. They don't need to be in same order to be same set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a different set:  you get the same elements back, but in a different order.  It looks like $1$ and $2$ were skipped, for instance, but $3\cdot 13=39\cong1\pmod{19}$ and $3\cdot 7=21\cong2\pmod{19}$.

Evidently,  multiplication by a nonzero $k$ gives a bijection from $\Bbb F_p\to\Bbb F_p$. (For $k$ is invertible in $\Bbb F_p$.)

Comment: Thank you. "in a different order" made me understand.